# On hovering div, text background color not changing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm tried to do , when i hover the  full div show to right side text effect, but its worked for the on the hover that right side text , how to appear hover div and show right side text background ,

Thanks

```css
.my-lst > :hover {
 
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

 .text-bg:hover {
 
  cursor: pointer; position:relative;
  color:#fff; display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
background: #25AAE1; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<main role="main" class="container">


  <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white my-lst  rounded shadow-sm">

    <div class="media text-muted border-bottom  pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <div class="text-bg">Follow</div>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
   

  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: add same effect on hover of parent div i.e .d-flex:hover .text-bg

Comment: i think in your example,  .media is the parent class. so add the same effect to that. i.e  .media:hover .text-bg {.....}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 .text-bg:hover , .media:hover .text-bg{
  cursor: pointer; position:relative;
  color:#fff; display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  background: #25AAE1; 
}
```